# Does AppHarbor support a SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, appharbor

Does anyone know if the solution can be deployed correctly with a project of this type included? I tried but keep getting this error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to include a local targets file, include it in the repository you push to AppHarbor and reference that. Here's some [related discussion for Silverlight projects](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1111-silverlight-5).

Comment: I did this and it still fails when executing the task: `<UsingTask TaskName="SqlBuildTask" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>`

Comment: Hm, Visual Studio is installed on the build servers so the dll should be available. You might want to experiment with including the dll in your repository and referencing the local dll from the targets file that you push. More resources here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/c2415cd6-ac8c-40a2-9d54-e19f07be023d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310164/appharbor-one-step-build-and-how-to-deploy-my-database

Comment: Referenced the assembly using `AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll"` and a local copy,  now I get: `CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql' failed because the assembly is built for an unsupported version of the Common Language Runtime.`