# AppHarbor one step build and how to deploy my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, msbuild, appharbor, dbproj

I finally got to the point where my solution does everything that's needed in it's build step:

- Download `NuGet` packages.
- Deploy the database (only if it's not there yet).
- Build the solution.
- Run any upgrade scripts (just once, the database keeps track of these).
- Run unit tests.
- *Succeed.*

This works all kinds of wonders locally.

Now I figured I'd integrate my [GitHub](http://github.com) repository with [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com), since CI was the next logical step for me.

Issue is, the database is being built in two steps:

- A `dbproj` is built, generating a `.dbschema`
- My database upgrader (sporting all its [DbUp](http://dbup.github.com/) awesomeness) builds, with a `BeforeBuild` target which builds and deploys the `dbproj`, and an `AfterBuild` target which self-executes the database upgrader, updating the schema with any SQL scripts that are yet to be run.

The issue is the [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com) build servers fail on the `.dbproj` project, because a required `SqlTasks.target` is missing in their server configuration.

I tried a quick fix manually adding that target (along with some other targets it depended on), but that yielded an error I can't get past:

> The "SqlBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql [...]

Digging a bit I found that [apparently](http://www.techques.com/question/1-3988879/Getting-MSBuild-and-CruiseControl-.NET-to-build-and-deploy-VS2010-database-projects) you can't build `.dbproj` projects on environments which do not have either `VS` nor `TFS` installed on them.

How should I proceed? I might have a few options:

- Manually connecting to the AppHarbor database and running the deployment script generated in my dev environment against a fresh production database.
  *This one kind of defeats the purpose of one-step building.*
- Instead of using a `.dbproj` database project, just include all base-install tables in the [DbUp](http://dbup.github.com) "upgrader".
  *This has two issues, although they probably can be resolved. The first one is that I should be creating the database by myself, the second one is that the `log4net` table I'm using to log the database upgrading process would be created by the process itself, which is all kinds of wrong in my books.*
- Use some custom database project solution where I can deploy a database without this issue.
  *I don't really know any solutions like this, do any exist, are they reliable?*

Opinions, deployment articles, or any suggestions are welcome, a quick hack to make .dbproj build on AppHarbor would also suffice.

Lastly, is it too far fetched to ask [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com) to include `TFS` and/or `VS` in their build servers, building `.dbproj` projects sounds fairly reasonable for a build server to do, right?

Comment: You might want to consider a different database deployment approach, such as this one: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3

Comment: I'm using dapper though. https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net

Comment: Quick hack to build dbproj - grab .target file and all dependent dlls (could be a big bunch, but I think it could be done). Store it along other build tools and inject it manually to your buildscript. 

This hack obviously violates Visual Studio product license and it's just a theory.

Actually I agree with friism and Niko - consider a different deployment approach. Maintainable and not violating anything.
Check ecm7Migrator as an option.

Comment: I tried that. didn't work out, one of the SQL targets threw exceptions about not being able to load assemblies dynamically (and they were all there)

Comment: You can prob get what you're after with http://www.pabich.eu/2011/03/automated-database-deployments-to.html